# ExcelAsyncUtil.Observe - to create a running clock in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asynchronous, excel-dna

I am trying out the ExcelAsyncUtil.Observe function. I made the following code that shows a running clock in Excel. It works fine but I am not sure what I am doing. Two questions:

1. Should I add functionality for observer.OnCompleted() and observer.OnError()? What does these calls do?
2. What should I do in the IDisposible class? Why is it there?

Here is my sample code:

```
    [ExcelFunction]
    public static object MyExcelTicker()
    {
        return ExcelAsyncUtil.Observe("MyExcelTicker", new object[] { }, TickerFunction());
    }

    public static ExcelObservableSource TickerFunction()
    {
        ExcelObservableSource source = new ExcelObservableSource(() => new TickerObservable());
        return source;
    }

    public class TickerObservable : IExcelObservable
    {
        public IDisposable Subscribe(IExcelObserver observer)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => observer.OnNext(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            timer.Start();     

            // What about observer.OnCompleted() and observer.OnError()?
            return new TickerDisposable();  
        }
    }

    public class TickerDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // What to do here?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while and at least one thing is still left not covered, so let me add to what Govert said.

You've asked:

```
public class TickerDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // What to do here?
    }
}
```

Let's summarize:

For each new subscriber to your clock-ticker, a Subscribe will be called on the TickerObservable. Therefore, for each subscriber, your code will create a new `System.Timers.Timer` and a new `timer.Elapsed` event handler - to get your intended effect. And this is actually all that **you** need to get your effect.

However, you are also required to return an IDisposable, therefore you've created a dummy TickerDisposable solely for that purpose, and you are not sure what it is for.

Answer:

The IDisposable that the library requires you to return from the Subscribe is there just to allow you to cleanup after your glitter stops shining. Timers are a "system thing". Once you create them and start them, they **run**. After an hour they cannot be GC'ed, because they are meant to be **run** until you stop them. Surely, you've +='ed an event hander, the observer (if weakly-reference'd) might be already dead, but your timer does not know! You must stop it at some point.

Hence, IDisposable-related pattern, borrowed from RX: whatever heavy or long-living you allocate, reserve, build, etc in the Subscribe method, put some note about it into that (yours!) IDisposable. Then, when the observer unsubscribes, your IDisposable will get cleaned too, and your **custom Dispose** method will be run, that will be able to look at your IDiposable's contents and .. cleanup the garbage, or rather, **unlock** it, so the GC can flush them.

Completing your example:

```
public class TickerObservable : IExcelObservable
{
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IExcelObserver observer)
    {
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => observer.OnNext(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        timer.Start();     

        return new TickerDisposable(timer);  
    }
}

public class TickerDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private Timer ticky;
    public TickerDisposable(Timer timer)
    {
        ticky = timer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(ticky != null)
            ticky.Dispose(); // or Stop, or etc..
    }
}
```

The above example is actually most-obvious usage of the returned IDisposable. However, you can use it for any register-unregister notification. For example, with single shared timer, it **might** look like this:

```
public class TickerObservable : IExcelObservable
{
    private static Timer timer = ..... ; // assume it is up & running & shared

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IExcelObserver observer)
    {
        ElapsedEventHander hd = (s, e) => observer.OnNext(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        timer.Elapsed += hd;

        return new TickerDisposable(timer, hd);  
    }
}

public class TickerDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private Timer ticky;
    private ElapsedEventHander handler;

    public TickerDisposable(Timer timer, ElapsedEventHander hd)
    {
        ticky = timer;
        handler = hd;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(ticky != null && handler != null)
            ticky.Elapsed -= handler;
    }
}
```

And now you are perfectly sure that no dead-handlers are lingering at the long-living-shared-timer. (of course the cleanup of the timer is missing here, but that's another thing..). Probably you already got the idea, so, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The **IExcelObserver** interface matches the semantics of the IObserver interface from the Reactive Extensions library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx).

You function can call **OnNext** zero or more times, and then call **OnError** if an error occurs, or **OnCompleted** if no further events will be raised. Excel-DNA will handle OnError as it would an exception thrown by a regular UDF, and will return #VALUE to the cell or process the exception  via the registered UnhandledExceptionHandler. OnCompleted is not so useful in the Excel context - it just indicates that no further values will be raised.

For your example, error don't seem to be a problem, and there is no end to the stream of events, so you need never call OnError or OnCompleted.

The Excel-DNA infrastructure will call the **IDisposable.Dispose** when the observable is no longer hooked up to a cell formula. For example, if the formula with the MyExcelTicker() call is deleted from the cell. You can use this as a notification to clean up any back-end resources, or ignore the notification if you're not interested.